# Django - annotate price= "price_A" or "price_B"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, django-queryset

I have multiple fields that stores the same value type (price) from different sources.

```
class Product...
    price_amazon = ...
    price_ebay = ...
    price_etsy = ...

    @property
    def price...
        return self.price_amazon or self.price_ebay or self.price_etsy
```

I'm looking for a way to annotate `price` to each `Product` from queryset. It should behave exactly as the `price` property.

`price` is either `price_amazon`, `price_ebay` or `price_etsy` - the first not None value.

How would you do that?

I tried:

```
Product.objects.all().annotate(price=F('price_amazon') or F('price_ebay') or F('price_etsy'))
```

which raises:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/.cloud/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/.cloud/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395 
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/.cloud/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 700     output = repr(obj)
    701     lines = output.splitlines()
    702     with p.group():

~/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/.cloud/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __repr__(self)
    261 
    262     def __repr__(self):
--> 263         data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
    264         if len(data) > REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE:
    265             data[-1] = "...(remaining elements truncated)..."

~/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/.cloud/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __len__(self)
    267 
    268     def __len__(self):
--> 269         self._fetch_all()
    270         return len(self._result_cache)
    271 

~/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/.cloud/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all(self)
   1306     def _fetch_all(self):
   1307         if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1308             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
   1309         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
   1310             self._prefetch_related_objects()

~/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/.cloud/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
     74             if annotation_col_map:
     75                 for attr_name, col_pos in annotation_col_map.items():
---> 76                     setattr(obj, attr_name, row[col_pos])
     77 
     78             # Add the known related objects to the model.

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) is all about. You can annotate with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Product.objects.annotate(
    price=Coalesce('price_amazon', 'price_ebay', 'price_etsy')
)
```